# shell commands with quotation marks in ranger

Tags: vim, ranger

I like to open the highlighted file in ranger in split of remote vim session.

```
:shell vim --remote-send "<C-\><C-n>:vsp %d/%f<CR>"
```

Rather than file `/path/to/directory/highlighted-file` I see in `vim` open file `'/path/to/directory'/'highlighted-file'` naturally I cannot save. I tried to escape percent symbols and quotation marks unsuccessfully. How to open current file in split of remote vim session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by changing double quotes to single ones:

```
:shell vim --remote-send '<C-\><C-n>:vsp %d/%f<CR>'
```